# "git checkout" leaving files deleted (unless I use -f)

Tags: git, version-control

**The Scenario**

I checkout an old branch - one that has fewer files than my active branch. I figure this is a pretty common thing.

I'm noticing that the following simple pair of commands is leaving a list of files marked as "Deleted" when I use **git status**.

**git checkout**  (say this branch contains files A, B, C)
**git checkout**  (containing A, B, C, D, and E)

At this point **git status** shows me D and E as *deleted from my working tree*. Worth noting, **git checkout  -f** shows my working directory clean (as I would expect when I have made no intentional changes).

---

**The Question**:

Based on the documentation for git checkout:

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree.

I would expect that specifying the **< active-branch >** tree-ish would cause my working directory to update to exactly that tree (i.e. with no changes in my working directory).

Why am I seeing deleted files unless I use **-f**?

Comment: When you checkout a different branch, you change the state of your workspace to that branch.  As such, files can disappear, if they were deleted in that other branch.  I'm not sure that anything you are seeing is out of the ordinary, or cause for alarm.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question: If I checkout a branch, my working directory should match the state of that branch. That is not happening here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm struggling to repro this with a smoke repository, so maybe the question is: what else could tweak how checkout deals with files?